# Setting fork and spawn in a maven plugin

Tags: java, ant, maven-plugin, hsqldb, spawn

We're converting a buildfile from ant to a maven plugin. We're trying to start/stop a database (hsqldb) in a maven plugin.

We succeeded to start the database. But we think that the plugin stops the database when the plugin is executed. The database should keep on running after the execution, but it seems to stop right away.

Our guess is that we should use the 'fork' and 'spawn' attributes (they are also in our build.xml from ant), but we don't have an idea how to implement them in our java class from our DatabaseController (which extends from AbstractMojo).

Any ideas?

We're using hsqldb, thisis the code how we initialize it:

```
hsqlServer = new Server();

hsqlServer.setLogWriter(null);
hsqlServer.setSilent(true);

hsqlServer.setDatabaseName(0, "database");
hsqlServer.setDatabasePath(0, "file:data/database");

getLog().info("Starting server!");
hsqlServer.start();
```

When we run the plugin, the database starts, we even managed to create tables and write data to it. Then the plugin stops, and the server stops automatically with it.

If we run another plugin, one to stop the server, we always get a nullPointerException at this line:

```
hsqlServer.stop();
```

Kind regards,

Jeroen

Comment: Well, if you get a NullPointerException at `hsqlServer.stop()`, then `hsqlServer` must be null, right? Or do you mean `hsqlServer.stop()` _throws_ a NullPointerException? In that case, please provide the stack trace.

Comment: The nullPointerException is fixed, and we're now able to run the database in the cmd. The thing is: when we run the plugin, the database still shuts down when the plugin is stopped. We created some kind of loop to keep the database alive, and it totally works then. The only problem now is: we can't do anything anymore in cmd, because the program is 'trapped' in the loop, and we want to avoid that. Maybe there are some other ways to fix this, but I can't think of something else than a fork and/or a spawn.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is, looking at existing maven plugins that does the forking of new java processes. Maven-surefire-plugin for one, do something similar. Surefire has a configuration (which will be specified in the pom.xml) called `forkMode`, which controlls the forking.
You may have to go through the [source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/surefire/tags/surefire-2.9/) (svn checkout the code) of the plugin to figure it out. 
I'm not much familiar with surefire much. But as a start, you may read the following class (`#fork( Object testSet, Properties...`)!

```
./maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/booterclient/ForkStarter.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Any code executed in maven is forked in another process. I worked with processes in some projects realm, it doesn't have a clear documentation about that.
You could call your code something like that:

```
Thread.currentThread().setDaemon(true);
hsqlServer = new Server();

hsqlServer.setLogWriter(null);
hsqlServer.setSilent(true);

hsqlServer.setDatabaseName(0, "database");
hsqlServer.setDatabasePath(0, "file:data/database");

getLog().info("Starting server!");
hsqlServer.start();
```

With an daemon thread, maven could thing witch your code is to be runned in background.
It´s supposition, but you could try it.